# How can I get rid of "IndexError: string index out of range"

Tags: python, index-error

I am trying to find neighbor nodes in a graph network. I have imported data in coa_train and now trying to find neighbor nodes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import isclose
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import os
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#from stellargraph import StellarGraph, datasets
#from stellargraph.data import EdgeSplitter
from collections import Counter
import multiprocessing
#from IPython.display import display, HTML
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

%matplotlib inline

def readTrainingData(tr):
    trainingData = []
    with open(tr) as f:
        for line in f:
            a1, a2 = line.strip().split()
            trainingData.append((a1, a2))
    return trainingData
coa_train = readTrainingData("training.txt")

coa_train

[('8193', '16056'),
 ('24578', '21968'),
 ('24578', '18297'),
 ('24578', '16770'),
 ('24578', '17038'),
 ('8195', '2072'),
 ('8195', '20568'),

----------------------
import collections

def getNeighbors(data):
    
    neighbors=collections.defaultdict(set)
    
    for pair in data:
        
        neighbors[pair[0]].add(pair[1])
        
        neighbors[pair[1]].add(pair[0])
        
        

        return neighbors

coa_neighbors= getNeighbors("coa_train")
```

Here, I am getting an error like:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-c775c56181f7> in <module>
     13         return neighbors
     14 
---> 15 coa_neighbors= getNeighbors("coa_train")
     16 

<ipython-input-41-c775c56181f7> in getNeighbors(data)
      5     for pair in data:
      6 
----> 7         neighbors[pair[0]].add(pair[1])
      8 
      9         neighbors[pair[1]].add(pair[0])

IndexError: string index out of range
```

I can't see any reason for this error,as I believe 0 and 1 index in coa_train data are valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass a string into the function

```
getNeighbors("coa_train")
```

but it should be the variable instead

```
getNeighbors(coa_train)
```

With a string as argument, the loop

```
for pair in data:
```

will give you single characters. And with a single character, you can't do `pair[1]` any more.

Comment: Thanks guys. It was helpful and all good now.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing string parameter to the function

```
coa_neighbors= getNeighbors("coa_train")
```

hence your,

```
for pair in data:
```

traverse single character from your string so that's why it gives index out of range error. try this..

```
coa_neighbors= getNeighbors(coa_train)
```

i hope it works.

Comment: This doesn't add anything extra to the previous answer.